# Trying to make alternate rows #eee background just using js

Tags: javascript, html

I can't seem to figure out why its not clicking here. The code doesn't have any syntax errors but obviously something wrong with logic. So basically as the first row is white the second row will be the other shade or `#eee`. If anyone can see the mistake and let me know I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
  
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var child = x[i].getElementsByTagName('tr');
    
    for (let j = 0; j < child.length; j += 2) {
      child[j].classList.add('alt');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.alt{
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>Table 1: Power Mac G5 tech specs </caption>
  <tr>
      <th>Configurations</th>
      <th>Dual 1.8GHz</th>
      <th>Dual 2GHz</th>
      <th>Dual 2.5GHz</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Model</td>
      <td>M9454LL/A</td>
      <td>M9455LL/A</td>
      <td>M9457LL/A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>G5 Processor</td>
      <td>Dual 1.8GHz PowerPC G5</td>
      <td>Dual 2GHz PowerPC G5</td>
      <td>Dual 2.5GHz PowerPC G5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Frontside bus</td>
      <td>900MHz per processor</td>
      <td>1GHz per processor</td>
      <td>1.25GHz per processor</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Level2 Cache</td>
      <td>512K per processor</td>
      <td>512K per processor</td>
      <td>512K per processor</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you have the css somewhere with `.alt`? What you have works for me.

Comment: I just edited your question and put the code together. Can you run the snipped and see fi that's what you want? I added css on your question and out `.alt { background: #eee; }` which was missing.

Comment: Now that you have the basis, you can change your js to move the greying to the bottom row instead of the first. Or follow the answers below to help you do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is perfect. You are adding `alt` class, but there is no style to make the background `#eee`. Either add a CSS class or add the background using JS.

Method 1:

```
.alt {
  background: #eee;
}
```

Method 2:

```
child[j].classList.add('alt');
child[j].style.background = '#eee'
```

Method 3: Using only CSS

```
table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName('table')
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var child = x[i].getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for (let j = 0; j < child.length; j = j + 2) {
      child[j].classList.add('alt');
      child[j].style.background = '#eee'
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table>

  <caption>Table 1: Power Mac G5 tech specs </caption>

  <tr>

    <th>Configurations</th>

    <th>Dual 1.8GHz</th>

    <th>Dual 2GHz</th>

    <th>Dual 2.5GHz</th>

  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>Model</td>

    <td>M9454LL/A</td>

    <td>M9455LL/A</td>

    <td>M9457LL/A</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>G5 Processor</td>
    <td>Dual 1.8GHz PowerPC G5</td>

    <td>Dual 2GHz PowerPC G5</td>

    <td>Dual 2.5GHz PowerPC G5</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>Frontside bus</td>

    <td>900MHz per processor</td>

    <td>1GHz per processor</td>

    <td>1.25GHz per processor</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>Level2 Cache</td>

    <td>512K per processor</td>

    <td>512K per processor</td>

    <td>512K per processor</td>

  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Spirit!! Exactly what I was looking for